# Does a hash-based storage cache design require additional access-control?

Tags: web-service, cloud-storage, design-flaw

Please forgive the vagueness of the question title.

I am currently working/designing an opaque storage of **immutable** files. The purpose of the service is simple: storing files and being able to retrieve them by their identifier.

As the service is explicitly designed at storing *immutable* data, I had the idea of making the files identifier dependent on the contents of the files themselves.

The formula is as follow:

```
file_id = file-size + SHA-256(file-content)
```

With that design, it is guaranteed that each file will have a deterministic and unique id.

I thought about how to protect the data with typical access control (typical HTTP Authorization strategies come to mind) but the more I think of it, the more it feels unnecessary.

My rationale is as follow: the valid identifier space is extremely large. So large that the only way an attacker could fetch a specific file is either:

1. Knowing the exact file content beforehand (allowing to compute the identifier).
2. Gaining access to an existing identifier in some other system.

But...

1. is... well. Idiotic: if you have the content of the file already, you don't need to access my storage service to fetch it.
2. Is a security design problem for the other systems: regardless of whether they store the real data or a reference to it, they need to be secure by themselves anyway.

**Should I still bother with an additional layer of security on top of my API or is that design secure enough in on itself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the features of your API and on how your storage is intended to be used.

- If your API provide a way to figure out IDs of existing resources (i.e. something like resource listings) then relying only on knowledge of the ID is surely not sufficient.
- If you fear that users might just save their IDs somewhere accessible to others and want some additional protection, then relying only on the ID is also not sufficient.
- If you want to implement a scheme where users might share resources with others but then revoke access later, then relying only on the ID is also not sufficient.
- Otherwise this might just be comparable to the commonly used unique URLs. Therefore see [Is a long, random string in a URL considered adequate protection from unauthorised access?](/questions/83801) or [Is random URL token secure enough for file attachments and other user content?](/questions/112021) for more information.